# Regarding iPhone Application Design Document

Tags: iphone

I am just entered into iPhone Application Development. I have to start the work on iPhone Application. And i have some Requirements Specification for particular application. Now for a starting phase i want to prepare a Design Document for that application. So, anyone can suggest me what i have to include in any mobile or iPhone Application ? If you have any same design document then please provide some link, if possible.

Or else, if you have any other idea for starting the application, then also you can suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step I'd always get the user interface down on paper with some mock-ups of screens, location of controls etc.

From that, I usually write in how the transitions between views are triggered and what information is flowing between different parts of the application with regards to the user interface.

Then, I decide on how I need to store the data in my application (usually a separate class) and how this will be accessed from the rest of the application.

A 3 or 4 page document will cover most small apps. I find doing the UI mock-up and basic data is enough to get going and get a bare bones app working.